# Documentation for Qt documentation comments? Qt + Doxygen?

Tags: c++, qt, documentation, doxygen, nokia

Where can I find documentation for Qt documentation comments? I'm referring to how Qt uses a specific style for documentation comments, like so:

```
/*!
    \class MyClassName
    \brief The MyClassName class is used as an example on Stack Overflow.

    This class serves a few functions, the most important being:

    \list
        \i So people can understand my question.
        \i So people can have a few laughs at the comedy in my example.
    \endlist
 */
```

...you get the picture. So where can I find information about all the switches, like \class, \list, \brief, etc. Also, what tool(s) do I use to generate documentation files from these comments in my source files? Does Doxygen support this syntax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use qdoc. [It is deprecated](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/918ca6151976ab43c330ff9ced9456837601a43a:tools/qdoc3/README.TXT). Use Doxygen, which is based on qdoc anyway.

That said, the documentation (in qdoc format :-D ) is [here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/918ca6151976ab43c330ff9ced9456837601a43a:tools/qdoc3/doc/qdoc-manual.qdoc).

Comment: I was looking for http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/pages/DocManual and http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/pages/DocMarkupCommands. Without knowing what it was called (qdoc, eh?) I couldn't Google it. A lot of the links seem to be dead though

Comment: Now, are you saying the qdoc *tool* is deprecated, or the entire qdoc *syntax* (including the tool) is deprecated? Nokia uses the qdoc syntax exclusively in Qt, is that just for backwards compatibility or should a different style (like Javadoc comments) be used instead? Obviously it's up to a programmer but I want to remain consistent with the rest of Qt or whatever Nokia recommends.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that spared me a lot of time. I was going for qdoc3 ... fool!

Comment: Are you sure the Qt Documentation is (still) deprecated?

The Link you provide is dead, and there is a [qdoc documentation in the current qt version](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qdoc/01-qdoc-manual.html).

Comment: The answer addresses Qt <= 4.8, since Qt 5 was released in 2012. The links now point to the intendend content. 
For what concerns Qt 5.x, qdoc3 has been renamed to qdoc. Long story short, it **can** be used for documentation **but** since it is developed to fulfill Qt documentation needs, it can change incompatibly from one version to another and it could be necessary to do some work to keep it running. [Longer story can be read here](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2014-October/018896.html).

Answer (score 3):

There are two parts of doxygen that are *qt-specific*: the *Qt Comment Style* and the QT_AUTOBRIEF Doxyfile configuration tag. These are simply parts of doxygen that are used by QT.  All doxygen comments used by QT are regular doxygen stuff.  So you just need to read up on doxygen.

Or perhaps are you really looking for documentation of QT internals, such as information on d-Pointers as contained in [this blog entry](http://zchydem.enume.net/2010/01/19/qt-howto-private-classes-and-d-pointers/)

**Qt Style Comments:**
The `/*! text */` comment style is called the "Qt Style" of doxygen comments.  The `!` marks the entire comment block as a doxygen comment block. It is a standard, optional part of doxygen.

**QT_AUTOBRIEF setting:**
if the "QT_AUTOBRIEF" tag is set to TRUE in the Doxyfile, the first line of a Qt style comment block is automatically interpreted as the \brief description.

From the doygen GUI help:

> QT_AUTOBRIEF tag is set to YES
>   then doxygen will interpret the first
>   line (until the first dot) of a
>   Qt-style comment as the brief
>   description. If set to NO, the
>   comments will behave just like regular
>   Qt-style comments (thus requiring an
>   explicit \brief command for a brief
>   description.)

Answer (score 1):

Use doxygen to create documentation

It can generate an on-line documentation browser (in HTML) and/or an off-line reference manual (LaTeX) from a set of documented source files. There is also support for generating output in RTF (MS-Word), PostScript, hyperlinked PDF, compressed HTML, and Unix man pages. The documentation is extracted directly from the sources, which makes it much easier to keep the documentation consistent with the source code.

You can configure doxygen to extract the code structure from undocumented source files. This is very useful to quickly find your way in large source distributions. You can also visualize the relations between the various elements by means of include dependency graphs, inheritance diagrams, and collaboration diagrams, which are all generated automatically.

http://www.doxygen.nl/

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the Qt source code itself for the Qt documentation comments...

[Qt - SRC - 4.6.3](http://get.qt.nokia.com/qt/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.3.zip)

I have used **DOxygen** for documentation and for me it's working fine, though the documentation standards are not of Qt. I suggest you to give it a try though and decide.